How can uboot-environment change from rootfs with fw_setenv?
my Linux operating system sometimes gives kernel panic while booting.
For this, I defined a variable in uboot called mybootcount. It will count every time it boots, if it reaches 3, it will go to the second partition, but after a successful boot, when it goes to rootfs, I need to access my env in Linux and set the mybootcount value to 0. I created a /etc/fw_env.config file for this. I made vi /dev/mmcblk1p1 0x140000 0x20000 and saved it, then when I do fw_printenv, I get the error warning: bad crc using default environment. But I don't get any warning during uboot loading.
my uboot config file
          CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_FAT=y
          CONFIG_ENV_FAT_DEVICE_AND_PART="1"
          CONFIG_ENV_SIZE=0X20000
          CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET=0X140000

my uboot loading
U-Boot 2019.04-linux4sam_6.2 (Oct 03 2024 - 10:35:02 +0300) MMC: sdio-host@a0000000: 0, sdio-host@b0000000: 1 Loading Environment from FAT... OK

printenv

bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4 panic=3 atmel.pm_modes=standby,ulp1
bootargs2=console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk root=/dev/mmcblk1p3 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4 panic=3  atmel.pm_modes=standby,ulp1
bootcmd=echo bootcounter: ${mybootcount}; run choose_bootargs; setexpr mybootcount ${mybootcount} + 1; saveenv; fatload mmc 1:1 0x21000000 at91-sama5d27_srcgb_mdm.dtb; fatload mmc 1:1 0x22000000 zImage; bootz 0x22000000 - 0x21000000 ;
bootcount=1
bootdelay=3
bootlimit=3
choose_bootargs=if test ${mybootcount} -ge ${bootlimit}; then echo "ROOTFS BACKUP"; setenv bootargs ${bootargs2}; setexpr mybootcount 0; else echo "MAIN ROOTFS"; fi; saveenv;
after kernel
fw_env.config:/dev/mmcblk1p1 0x140000 0x20000
fw_printenv
bootcmd=bootp; setenv bootargs root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootpath} ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}:${hostname}::off; bootm
bootdelay=5
baudrate=115200
mybootcount=0

In /etc/fw_env.config, try /dev/mmcblk1p1 0x0 0x20000, or maybe /dev/mmcblk1 0x140000 0x20000 ... the offset may be from the start of the device, not the partition (?) ... just a guess.

yes you are right. I use fat environment thus it is not important my config size and config  offset.I made hexdump /dev/mmcblk1p1 and i saw true config offset.

So, what exactly was I right about? (and what was the final contents of /etc/fw_env.config?)

After doing hexdump I saw that my config offset was at 0xc800.I changed my fw_env.config /dev/mmcblk1p1 0xc800 0x4000 and later i made fw_printenv,  true environment.

You could write your own answer (and accept it) which explains how you arrived at those values (0xc800 0x4000), which are quite different to the uboot ones (not sure what "config offset" is, presumably a kernel config param?). Note also that I would be very wary about writing to flash during boot (especially a failed boot) - for example, the panic might be because of heat problems (I have seen flash reads and writes fail if a board is running hot). Your goal should be to almost never write to flash, as there is a limit to the number of writes you can do (in the order of 10s of thousands?).
